# Why does Bootstrap display wrong pencil icon?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want this icon on my page which I found at [http://glyphicons.bootstrapcheatsheets.com](http://glyphicons.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/)

[image]

However, when the HTML it gives me:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
```

displays this icon:

[image]

**How can I get the first pencil icon instead of the second?**

---

**ADDENDUM:** `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>` gives me:

[image]

---

**ADDENDUM:** I download Bootstrap again and copied the font files into my font directory, but still get the wrong icons:

[image]

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using?\

Comment: Perhaps you have a wrong/outdated version of the glyphicons-halflings-regular.* files in your /fonts folder

Comment: Try redownloading bootstrap files

Comment: I redownloaded the font files (see above) but still get wrong icons.

Comment: Are you downloading bootstrap files from the "Customize" page or home page? Because downloading from the customizer can result in corrupted files sometimes

Answer (score 1):

THANKS EVERYONE, I figured it out:

I replaced my local references to bootstrap js and css with the CDN links:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional: Include the jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Optional: Incorporate the Bootstrap JavaScript plugins -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and it worked, which led me to discover that I had multiple bootstrap files locally. I cleaned that up, am pointing to the right ones, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over riding some thing like font awasome
try fa fa-pencil as class
or instead of span use i tag

Comment: If he is using bootsrap 3 he can't use <i> tag for icons.He has to use <span> tag because <i> has been replaced

Comment: `<span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>` gives me nothing, and `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>` gives me the same pencil that I don't want.

Comment: icon-pencil try this one

Comment: `<span class="icon icon-pencil">` and `<span class="glyphicon icon-pencil"></span>` show me nothing